# how can I use chai.js to test if my function creates an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bdd, chai

I am starting to learn chai.js - very useful. I am stuck on understanding how to use chai to test if my function successfully creates an array.

This is an earlier test that passes:

```
describe('wordSearch', function() {
  it("takes an input and returns a changed input to the screen", function() {
    expect(wordSearch("hello world", "world", "hello universe")).to.equal("hello universe");
  });
})
```

and I found some examples here: http://www.andrewsouthpaw.com/2015/01/08/beginners-guide-to-testing-with-mocha-chai/

(see his bubblesort function, towards the end of the page)

But some pointers on understanding how I can test this functionality would be super helpful. Is it necessary to have the functionality that captures a string and turns it into an array live in its own function?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Chai has some functions for checking types.

If you use Assert you can simply do:

```
assert.isArray(yourValue);
```

For Expect you should be able to do:

```
expect(yourValue).to.be.an('array');
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer can be updated, sorry I can't comment yet ;)
If I understand You corectly Your function/method returns an array of strings from input parameters...

```js
describe('wordSearch', function() {
  it('takes an input and returns a changed input to the screen', function() {
    var output = wordSearch('hello world', 'world', 'hello universe'); 
    expect(output).to.be.an('array');
    expect(output).to.include('hello universe');
  });
});
```